# ng-change is fired a second time when selected option is removed from ng-options - AngularJS 1.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-1.6

I have a list of sale items and for each sale item there is a dropdown box where you can select from a list of available IDs to assign to the sale item. The selection must be unique for each sale item. If 2 is selected from saleItem1 dropdown, 2 cannot be available in the dropdown for saleItem2.

After selecting an ID from the dropdown list I need to remove it from the list and replace it with the old ID. Selecting an ID fires the ng-change which updates the list correctly. However the line marked with an asterix, which removes the selected ID from the list, causes ng-change to be fired again with a null value as the new ID.

I am struggling to find a solution to work around this.

The same code works fine in AngularJS 1.2, but after moving to 1.7 I am seeing this issue.

```
$scope.updateSaleItemIds = function(saleItem, newid) {
    var ind = $scope.availableSaleItemIds.indexOf(newid);
    if (!isNaN(saleItem.id)) {
        *$scope.availableSaleItemIds[ind] = saleItem.id;*
    }
    else {
        $scope.availableSaleItemIds.splice(ind,1);
    }
    $scope.availableSaleItemIds.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    var indE = $scope.saleItems.indexOf(saleItem);
    $scope.saleItems[indE].id = newid;
};
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="saleItem in saleItems" class="createForm">
    <select ng-model="selectedId"
        ng-options="id for id in availableSaleItemIds"
        ng-change="updateSaleItemIds(saleItem, selectedId)">
        <option value="">{{saleItem.id}}</option>
    </select>
</tr>
```

Comment: @georgeawg done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS V1.4 included a major refactoring of the `ng-options` directive. The default option is now selected with a model value of `null`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.4 - ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions).

When the user selects an option, the model is set to that new value and the `ng-change` updates the available options. The `updateSaleItemsIds` function removes that value from the `availableSaleItemIds` list. When the new list of options does not include the model value, the `ng-options` directive sets the model back to `null` and invokes the `ng-change` directive again.

The work around is to not update the list of options when the selected value is changed to `null`.

```
<select ng-model="selectedId"
    ng-options="id for id in availableSaleItemIds"
    ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶=̶"̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶S̶a̶l̶e̶I̶t̶e̶m̶I̶d̶s̶(̶s̶a̶l̶e̶I̶t̶e̶m̶,̶ ̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶I̶d̶)̶"̶
    ng-change="selectedId && updateSaleItemIds(saleItem, selectedId)">
    <option value="">{{saleItem.id}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.
If I have more than one dropdown,and I select a value in one drop down. This value must then become unavailable as an option in all the other dropdowns. 
Also the previously selected value must then be added to the list of available options so it can be selected for another sale item.

Comment: Are you saying you tried this and it didn't work? It will update the `availableSalesItemIds` if the selection has a value. It only skips the second change if that change is to `null`. See this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UxyzuxmYTCZIu5yYtTIS?p=preview).

Comment: I made a mistake and did not add 'selectedId' to ng-change. Your solution does indeed work, thanks very much.